# You need the NDKv8b or later when build VLC

Tags: android, ubuntu, vlc

I have build VLC in android with codes implement:

```
  jack--:~$ export ANDROID_SDK=android-sdk
  jack--:~$ export ANDROID_NDK=android-ndk-r9d
  jack--:~$ export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK/tools
  jack--:~$ export ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
```

But i'm using the NDK revision 9
The problem show "You need the NDKv8b or later". How do i solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this :

```
export ANDROID_NDK=~/.android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130729/android-ndk-r9d
```

This will solve the problem.

That is use ~/ before your NDK path.

Comment: I got the same error with NDK r10d, Android 5.0.1 (Api 21) and Ubuntu 12.04.
My ndk folder is under "/opt/adt-bundle-linux" location.
So what command I have to use?
export ANDROID_NDK=~/opt/adt-bundle-linux/android-ndk-r10d
or
export ANDROID_NDK=~/.opt/adt-bundle-linux/android-ndk-r10d
What is the meaning of . after ~/ ??

Comment: Not helping...........
can you tell
why it is coming and how it got solved in your case