# You need the NDKr9 or later

Tags: android, git, android-ndk, git-bash, vlc-android

I tried to build [android-vlc](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk) and [ijkPlayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer) using Git, and after following the steps and making the required sdk and ndk exports for each one, both lead me to the same error message through Git-Bash which is:

```
You need NDKr9 or later
```

I have **NDKr9b** and **NDKr10d** and I got this error message with both of them, and after having a look at android-vlc sdk [source code](https://github.com/mstorsjo/vlc-android/blob/master/compile.sh) I found that it just checking the **/RELEASE.TXT** file in the ndk provided path:

```
# try to detect NDK version
REL=$(grep -o '^r[0-9]*.*' $ANDROID_NDK/RELEASE.TXT 2>/dev/null|cut -b2-)
case "$REL" in
    9*|10*)
        GCCVER=4.8
        CXXSTL="/"${GCCVER}
    ;;
    7|8|*)
        echo "You need the NDKv9 or later"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

and when checking it my self for NDK10, I found that it only contains one line which is:

> r10d (64-bit)

and in NDK9 it is:

> r9b

which supposed to make the code run without problems in both cases, so what am I missing here?

**p.s.** I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091285/you-need-the-ndkv8b-or-later-when-build-vlc) which provides the same problem but it's answer doesn't work with me.

Comment: Did you find any solution?!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde unfortunately No, you may search for an already built sample then download and use it by editing it's code or just referencing it.

Comment: I passed this error; On windows, I run bash command in command prompt, and then it detect my correct NDKr10e. Please test it and if it work for you too, tell me to post it as answer.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde well, you can post an answer with what specifically did you tried and what you got, and I will test it and tell you what I got.